# Assistance with output of this algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Using the following code, what will the array `nums` contain after 2 full passes?

```java
int [] nums = {10, 6, 2, 9, 3, 1, 11};

for (int x=0; x<nums.length; x++)
{
    int largest = x;
    for (int y=x+1; y<nums.length; y++)
    {
        if (nums[y]>nums[largest])
            largest=y;
    }

    if (largest!=x)
    {
        int temp=nums[x];
        nums[x]=nums[largest];
        nums[largest]=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to print the array values after every pass and you will get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code is basically arranging numbers in an array in descending order. I appreciate the use of nested loop as most of the sorting algorithms are implemented with nested loop.

Coming to the answer and its explanation,

```
int largest = x;
```

This line of code assigns the current array index to variable largest. Initially, largest is 0. The loop after this line is checking whether a number at other locations is greater than the number at index largest or not. If a number is greater, than largest gets that index.

The condition (largest!=x) checks whether the initially assigned index is changed at all. After the first pass, largest contains 6 which is not equal to 0. As a result, swapping takes place.

The output after first pass is
11, 6, 2, 9, 3, 1, 10

Following the same pattern, the output after second pass is
11, 10, 2, 9, 3, 1, 6